# Many-Many self joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Users table that joins to a Friends table that links back to a user.

So

```
User
ID | Name
has_many :friends, :through => :friends

Friend
ID | user_id | friend_id | relationship
belongs_to :friends, :foreign_key => "friend_id", :class_name => "User"
```

This works fine, however when I have a specific user and call

```
friends = me.friends
```

I am getting an array of users, however I need both tables information so I want

```
ID | name | relationship
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `return`? Give us some more context and what you're tying to accomplish

Comment: see revision for clarity. I believe I am approaching this problem the wrong way for rails in that I'm essentially trying to return two model objects in one hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this for self-referential association http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Now for getting relationship information from friendships(/friends table in your example) table do following

```
User.includes(:friendships).all # some other conditions ?
```

See this for more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations